# Creating a Map from an Array of int - Operator '%' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Object'

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, collectors

I have code like this, which is supposed to create a `Map` from an array of integers. The *key* represents the *number of digits*.

```
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> groupByDigitNumbersArray(int[] x) {
    return Arrays.stream(x)  // array to stream
        .filter(n -> n >= 0) // filter negative numbers
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> Integer.toString((Integer) n).length(), // group by number of digits
            Collectors.mapping(d -> (d % 2 == 0 ? "e" : "o") + d,
                Collectors.toList()))); // if even e odd o add to list
}
```

The problem is in the line with `mapping()`.
I'm getting an error:

```
Operator '%' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Object', 'int'
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flavor of [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) that expects a `Collector` as an argument isn't available with *primitive streams*. Even without a modulus operator `%`, your code will not compile - comment out the *downstream collector* of `groupingBy()` to see what I'm talking about.

You need to apply `boxed()` operation in order to convert an `IntStream` into a stream of objects `Stream<Integer>`.

Your method might look like this:

```
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> groupByDigitNumbersArray(int[] x) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(x)  // creates a stream over the given array
        .filter(n -> n >= 0) // retain positive numbers and zero
        .boxed()             // <- converting IntStream into a Stream<Integer>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            n -> String.valueOf(n).length(), // group by number of digits
            Collectors.mapping(d -> (d % 2 == 0 ? "e" : "o") + d, // if even concatinate 'e', if odd 'o'
                Collectors.toList()))); // collect to list
}
```

I've changed the `classifier` function of `groupingBy()` to be more readable.